# Error setting up cscope 15.8 on when creating file cscope.files

Tags: 14.04, command-line

I'm running native Ubuntu 14.04.  I'm trying to install `cscope-15.8a`.  When I run the command:

```
find . -name "*.c" -o -name *.cpp" -o -name "*.h" -o -name "*.hpp" > cscope.files
```

It changes the prompt from `$` to `>`

I don't know what shell I'm running or what I've done to my console. How do I run this command without causing this problem?  The file `cscope.files` does not get created.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have mismatched (unbalanced) quotes, so the shell thinks you haven't finished typing the quoted string - the `>` is prompting you for a continuation. Also you are presumably missing some `*` glob characters - to find any `.c`, `.cpp`, `.h` or `.hpp` files it needs to be

```
find . -name "*.c" -o -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.h" -o -name "*.hpp" > cscope.files
```